# change file permissions in ubuntu through command line

Tags: permissions

How will I change a file permission so that it can be read?This is my file:

```
koha-conf.xml  -rw-r-----
```

Comment: That is already readable!!

Answer (score 3):

To make it readable to everyone

you can provide the command

chmod 777  koha-conf.xml

where 7 is divided into  three value 4 (read) + 2 (write) + 1 (execute)

so it would be accessible by all user & all groups & everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Looks readable if you are the user that owns it, or are in the group that owns it.

Try:

```
chown your-user-name:owner-group koha-conf.xml
```